# Generic bound ensuring non-reference argument

Tags: rust

The real reason to do this is beyond the scope, I just can say that it's related to a very unusual memory layout on some embedded platform. The goal is to make a wrapper for statics which can do some manual address translation on dereferencing. So putting a reference inside is pointless and unsafe. Alternatively I can make two implementations for references and not references but they must be strongly unambiguous.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Your question is unclear: before we can give any answer, you have to give more details. Besides that, maybe you want the `'static` lifetime? It prevents the type having any reference that doesn't "outlive" your program.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this but it requires the nightly features [`negative_impls`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/negative-impls.html) and [`auto_traits`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/unstable-book/language-features/auto-traits.html):

```
#![feature(negative_impls)]
#![feature(auto_traits)]

auto trait NotRawRef {}

impl<T> !NotRawRef for &T {}
impl<T> !NotRawRef for &mut T {}

fn foo<T: NotRawRef>(_: T) {}
```

This will apply recursively *by default*, so `T` cannot be a user-defined type that contains a reference -- unless the user-defined type explicitly implements `NotRawRef`.  You have to trust callers of your function not to implement this trait when it's not appropriate.

---

If nightly isn't an option, or if this is too strict, you can rather easily bound on "if there are any references, they must have static lifetime" with `'static`. For example:

```
fn foo<T: 'static>(_: T) { }

fn main() {
    let x = 1;
    foo(x);

    // The following line would fail with E0597:
    // foo(&x);

    // Works because the reference has static lifetime
    foo(&1);
}
```

This bound applies to user-defined types that have generic lifetime parameters as well, and will reject any such type with a non-`'static` lifetime argument.

Comment: No, it's not about static lifetime, it's about no reverences at all for a platform-specific reason

Comment: @e_asphyx Let me rewrite the answer to address that.

Comment: @cdhowie I'd recommend adding back your previous answer for reference - I figure that `'static` may be enough.

Comment: @PitaJ Fair, I'll do that.

Comment: What? [Surely the version with auto-traits applies recursively](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=31b8cac43672188a63a79d82f8b71c4d).

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Interesting, I didn't realize auto traits did that. I suppose you can "break" that intentionally with `impl NotRawRef for Foo {}` so you have to trust your callers aren't going to try to circumvent the intent of the bound.

Comment: @cdhowie If you don't want to trust your callers, you can make the trait `unsafe`.